# Is there any way to upload screenshots directly to FTP or image hosting and give me the url?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Is there any application for screenshots that could upload directly to FTP or any image hosting site and just give me the URL?

I come from the Windows world, where I got used to [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), where you basically press print screen, click on FTP and it copies the URL into clipaboard so you can immediately paste it for example on IM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two of the best apps for this are [**CloudApp**](http://getcloudapp.com/) and [**Skitch**](http://skitch.com/).

Cloud app has an option to automatically upload screenshots (image courtesy of Softpedia). It is very drag and drop friendly and pastes the URL to your clipboard for convenience.

Skitch is a little more heavy on the screen snapping controls. It's like grab on steroids. You can quickly hide private information, point out items, and edit the snap before uploading.

The free version of both are well worth it. Both have paid upgrades that are low cost, but you don't need to pay to use either. I have also heard really good things about [Droplr](http://droplr.com/hello) so you might check it out as well.

[image]

Both [CloudApp](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud/id417602904?mt=12) and [Skitch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12) are available on the App Store. The two are better together - skitch is better for grabbing a great screen shot, and droplr for upload and sharing it.

Comment: None of the above do FTP - but all three are really great.

Comment: Skitch does FTP now @bmike

Comment: Interesting @Kaj - I'm looking at Skitch v  2.7.8 for OS X and don't see the way to get from the app to a FTP server or how to copy the URL either. Are you using transmit or another tool to mount the ftp locally?

Comment: Same @bmike - Preferences -> Share and there you can add accounts. Screenshotted it (sorry, it's not in english but I guess the layout of the buttons etc will be the same): http://img.sunbow.be/Schermafbeelding_2016-05-20_om_14_29_55_1CEF3B09.png

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) (and you should), I recommend [GrabBox](http://grabbox.devsoft.no/). When you take a regular screenshot (command-shift-3, command-shift-4, etc.) it automatically uploads it to your public folder, grabs the public URL, optionally shortens it, and copies it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

i think tinygrab (http://tinygrab.com/features.php) can do it

you can also roll your own if you want.

Here is a [link to the code below](http://pastie.org/2245251) for working with imgur:

```
#!/bin/sh
# version 0.3
# 2010-02-12
# description: bash alternative to grabup using imgur.com
# todo: add error code checking/reporting
#       report upload speed & time via growl
#       copy to clipboard on 'click on notification'

apikey="7d9157e3bb2823aadb62a40e30e10dcc"
growlecho (){ echo $@ | /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t QuickGrab -a /Applications/Utilities/Grab.app; }

# work in temporary directory
tempdir=`mktemp -dt quickgrab`
cd $tempdir

# start screencapture in interactive mode unless...
if [[ "$1" == "-m" ]]
then
    screencapture -m tmpfile.png
else
    screencapture -i tmpfile.png
fi

# check if tmpfile.png exists before continuing
if [ -f tmpfile.png ]
then
    # upload via imgur.com api & output to response.log
    curl -F "image=@tmpfile.png" -F "key=$apikey" http://imgur.com/api/upload.xml > response.log
    LOGFILE=./response.log

    # if no errors (return 1), copy url
    A1=`xpath $LOGFILE "/rsp/@stat='ok'"`
    if [[ "$A1" == "1" ]]
    then
        # copy url to clipboard & growl success
        echo `xpath $LOGFILE "//original_image/text()"` | pbcopy
        growlecho `xpath $LOGFILE "//original_image/text()"`
    else
        # growl failure
        growlecho "$A1"
    fi
fi

# delete temporary directory
rm -r $tempdir
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dropshare](http://getdropsha.re/) is another paid option that has come along - in the vein of TinyGrab and LittleSnaper (which Realmac has [replaced with Ember](http://help.realmacsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/200159952-Upgrade-from-LittleSnapper-to-Ember)) mentioned already.

Both the OS X and iOS version can:

- Upload to S3, Rackspace or your own server (via SCP over SSH)
- Global hotkeys for uploading clipboard, screenshot/recording or note (MarkDown supported)
- Create optional, custom landing pages for your files
- Sync connections/preferences via Dropshare's own sync service
- Shorten URLs using services or custom shorteners
- Delete previously shared files directly via the app

Three-day trial of the OS X version's available at [their site](http://getdropsha.re/).

[image: Screenshot from Dropshare's website]

I've been pleased using it for the past few months.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small python script to do that.
It will not just auto upload screenshots to imgur but also copy screenshot url to clipboard and open up browser with link instantly.
Check it out:

[Video Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSHaXGYkEOw):

[Link](http://iyask.me/AutoScreenshotUploader/)

Answer (score -1):

[LittleSnapper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/littlesnapper/id403489261?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) is designed to work with FTP and copy the URL after upload. Upload is a separate step from snapping, so you will have to set a key command or automate that for the exact functionality you ask.

There is a free trial version from the [RealMac website](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) - so you can see if it's what you want before buying a license.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clicked the link: apple not available in UK store, WTF....

Comment: @sorin since this is 2019 (almost 2020) and a -1 answer, I doubt it’s worth updating and expect most people will realize that software isn’t around today.

Comment: We should all aim to remove noise, like invalid answers. A downvote is the best I can do to make an invalid answer less visible. Is only about UX: less (noise) is better (for the reader).

Comment: I agree and down votes / keeping wrong answers can often be as useful as a good answer. In this case - I don’t think the links will help find a newer version so I’ll likely remove it once I can make sure it’s devoid of data. I appreciate very much the vote and the comment.